# Angular 8 validator for input with type number

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an input with a type number which allows by default the insert of some characters like '+' '-' '.'

**HTML**

```
   <input   type="number"
              class="form-control"
              formControlName="numberChildren"/>
```

**TypeScript**

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm(): void {
    this.personalForm= this.formBuilder.group({
        numberChildren: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]{2}')]],

    })
  }
```

I want to implement a logic which accept only numbers without '+' '-' '.'

*Note: it is mandatory to use number as type of the input*

Comment: accept only number will not work here validators just test the value is it ok or not 

Comment: `Note: it is mandatory to use number as type of the input` ← Why?

Comment: check this library  https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask

Comment: @Igor, The end-user expect to have inputs that allow only the typing of values numeric.

Comment: `The end-user expect to have inputs that allow only the typing of values numeric` ← Are you referring to a touch display (phone / tablet)  and the keyboard that pops up? Perhaps there is a way to default to a numeric key set (0-9 and symbols) instead of the QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register to the `keypress` event to ignore characters you do not want like the `+` character. This might also be more user friendly because there is no error message displayed, it just stops the character from being added to the input.

```
<input type="number"
  class="form-control"
  (keypress)="($event.charCode === 8 || $event.charCode === 0 || $event.charCode === 13) ? null : $event.charCode >= 48 && $event.charCode <= 57"
  formControlName="numberChildren"/>
```

The `charCode` is the [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/) used. This will allow numbers as well as ENTER and BackSpace.